# SQL Sum function returning wrong quantity with inner join can't get subquery working

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

the following code is outputting the wrong figure, I want a sum the total units invoiced on every invoice, where invoice date is between '2022-11-01' and '2022-11-30'
Date is found on SalesInvoice table, the quantity is found in the SalesInvoiceLine table
They are joined on SalesInvoiceId

This is the original code I wrote which outputs the wrong quantity:

```
select sum(SIL.QuantityInvoice) as QtyInv, 
from dr.SalesInvoiceLine SIL 
inner join dr.SalesInvoice as SI 
  on SI.SalesInvoiceId = SIL.SalesInvoiceId
where SI.TransactionDate between '2022-11-01' and '2022-11-30'
```

I have tried introducing a subquery but cannot get it working as requires group by and I'm not doing that correctly:

```
select SalesInvoiceId, 
  sum(QuantityInvoice) QtyInv 
from dr.SalesInvoiceLine SIL 
join (
  select SI.SalesInvoiceId 
  from dr.SalesInvoice SI 
  inner join dr.SalesInvoiceLine SIL2
    on SIL2.SalesInvoiceId = SI.SalesInvoiceId 
  where SI.TransactionDate between '2022-12-01' and '2022-12-31'
  )
```

I've looked at a number of resources and tried several alternatives but can't get the subquery version working.

Is a subquery the correct way to solve this and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Please add sample data.  Please add sample schema.  We can not help without them.  Added bonus, put the scripts in SQL Fiddle using the correct flavor of your RDBMS please.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: You tagged "group by" yet don't use it anywhere? Yet it does sound like that's the solution. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you just need to group by each invoice using `SalesInvoice.SalesInvoiceId`.

```
 select sum(SIL.QuantityInvoice) as QtyInv, 
 from dr.SalesInvoiceLine SIL 
 inner join dr.SalesInvoice as SI 
  on SI.SalesInvoiceId = SIL.SalesInvoiceId
 where SI.TransactionDate between '2022-11-01' and '2022-11-30'
 group by SI.SalesInvoiceId
```

Comment: I just edited the question as I'm trying to solve a more simplified version of the code (copy/pasted the wrong query), would your solution work with the updated query?

Comment: I bet it would. You are summing many values joined from a child table based on a key in the parent table. You can use any valid aggregation on the child table and even use those results in calculations against the parent table.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me approach the problem different and uncover what the actual issue was. Not that I couldn't use group by. It actually wasn't required for what I was originally trying to do, I know now. What I discovered as that a bunch of sales invoices have a deposit line where the unit charge and unit quantity are reversed. For instance a deposit of $150 units is recorded as 155 units at $1. There was a reason why my unit totals were wildly overstated but not caused by the sum in my query.